# Using Pandas to merge two files with duplicates repeats the first row of the first file

Tags: python, pandas, merge, export-to-csv, mp3

I have two csv files that I want to do a conditional join on. The **first** is as follows:

```
File path;Song title;Artist names;Album title;Track number;Duration seconds
"Inverno.mp3";"Inverno";"Unknown";"Unknown";"0";280
"Inverno(1).mp3";"Inverno(1)";"Unknown";"Unknown";"0";280
"Soldier, Soldier.mp3";"Soldier, Soldier";"Natalie Merchant";"The House Carpenter's Daughter";"06";225
"Surely.mp3";"Surely";"Unknown";"Unknown";"0";31
"Intro.mp3";"Intro";"intro";"TEJO Beat";"01";30
```

With 17543 lines + header

The **second** one is missing the file path, but has information missing on the first:

```
Song title,Album title,Artist names,Duration seconds
Inverno,Perfil,Adriana Calcanhotto,280
Inverno,Fabrica Do Poema,Adriana Calcanhotto,280
"Soldier, Soldier",The House Carpenter's Daughter,Natalie Merchant,225
Surely,Supertramp,Supertramp,31
Intro,TEJO Beat,intro,30
```

This one has 17560 + header

These files are supposed to describe 17543 mp3 files and 5 m4a files.
The **first** has file name, but several files with "Unknown" fields.
The **second** has all the tags, but no file name.
The only way to positively ID a file is by combining the "Song Title" and "Duration seconds" fields, and there are still a few duplicates.

I want a csv file with all the information for the files that have "Unknown" fields.

I used the following with pandas to generate a merged file:

```
keycol = ["Song title", "Duration seconds"]

include_values = ["Unknown"]

first = pandas.read_csv(firstfile,sep=None,engine='python')

second = pandas.read_csv(secondfile,sep=None,engine='python')
merged = first.merge(second, on=keycol)

mergedfiltered = merged[merged[['Album title_x', 'Artist names_x']].isin(include_values).all(axis=1)]
header = ["File path","Song title","Artist names","Album title","Track number","Duration seconds"]
column_list = ["File path", "Song title", "Artist names_y","Album title_y","Track number", "Duration seconds"]
mergedfiltered.to_csv(destination,index=False, sep=";",columns=column_list, header=header)
```

The issue here is if there are two files with duplicate song title, like Inverno.mp3 and Inverno(1).mp3 and that have the same duration (same track and artist, different albums - usually), the end file, instead of having **"Inverno.mp3;Inverno;Adriana Calcanhotto;Perfil;0;280"** on one row and **"Inverno(1).mp3;Inverno;Adriana Calcanhotto;Fabrica Do Poema;0;280"**, has instead the second row with the same file name and different tags - **"Inverno.mp3;Fabrica Do Poema;Adriana Calcanhotto;album2;0;280"**

```
File path;Song title;Artist names;Album title;Track number;Duration seconds
"Inverno.mp3";"Inverno";"Perfil";"Adriana Calcanhotto";"0";280
"Inverno.mp3";"Inverno";"Fabrica Do Poema";"Adriana Calcanhotto";"0";280
"Soldier, Soldier.mp3";"Soldier, Soldier";"Natalie Merchant";"The House Carpenter's Daughter";"06";225
"Surely.mp3";"Surely";"Supertramp";"Supertramp";"0";31
"Intro.mp3";"Intro";"intro";"TEJO Beat";"01";30
```

How can I make sure that pandas.merge also uses the second file name, that is, when it changes row on the second file it also changes on the first instead of repeating the first row/column of the first file?

Comment: Why do the frames have different length? Don't they describe the same music files? I'm asking because the solution would be trivial for the frames of same dimensions.

Comment: One (first) is generated by me from the existing files and the extracted tags. The second was with the file backup. I can only assume that 11 files weren't recovered from the backup. I've already thought of identifying the differences and either cutting that from the second or adding it with fake file names to the first,,,

Answer (score 0):

The way I see this, you can't do what you are asking for.

Let's take the example you offer. In the first file, you have "Inverno" and "Inverno(1)", with unknown author/album. In the second file, you have "Inverno" and "Inverno" with same durations, with known (and different) author/album. How would a computer know which line to pick from the second file? It simply doesn't have the information to know what tags should be applied. In your case, it actually matches on file duration, hence the title not being carried through.

Either your frames have data that can be uniquely matched (then your approach with `merge` will work), or you have frames with rows corresponding to same files (then you can just directly replace the data, like below).

```py
df1.loc[df1['Artist names'] == 'Unknown', 'Artist names'] = df2.loc[df1['Artist names'] == 'Unknown', 'Artist names']
df1.loc[df1['Album title'] == 'Unknown', 'Album title'] = df2.loc[df1['Album title'] == 'Unknown', 'Album title']
```

Comment: Ok, it looks like I'll have to do some "massaging" of the frames before merging. Possibly checking for duplicates, and changing the title on the second entry on D2 to have the (1) or (2) or whatever would fit with the entry on D1. Either that or going by hand on the resulting file and fixing the file names.